# Arbitrary switching of a large number of analog signals

Tags: audio, switching

I'm thinking about building a programmable patch bay for analog audio signals. There would be 24 analog inputs x 24 analog outputs with switching of any input to any output. Only one signal at a time per output (no mixing) but any input needs to be routable to any output. Control would be done from a small 8 bit MCU of some type.

I'm having trouble finding a solution for the switching that doesn't involve dozens (hundreds?) of 8 channel multiplexer/switch ICs. I found some 16 channel mux and switching chips, but those are considerably more expensive (and I'd still need a lot of them).

Is there some solution that I'm missing, or are there relatively cheap switching ICs that have 24 inputs (or 24 outputs; I think it could be done either way)?

Comment: How many paths through do you actually need? If you need 24 through then you need 576 switches (assuming mono), in whatever form. The AD8113 seems comparably reasonably priced but you 'd need 4 to get (up to) 32 x 32 and that's about $120-$150 just for the chips. Analog crosspoint switches don't tend to be cheap.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for; something like the AD8113. I just didn't know the name "crosspoint switch" so I wasn't finding anything like that. I'd mark this as answered and/or vote for that response, but I'm not sure if that option's available to me yet (not seeing any option to do that) as I just created this account.

Comment: Would it be heretical to consider digitizing your signals, then using a digital switch and reconverting them to analog? That could be done in a small-ish FPGA. Then you'd avoid lots of nasty analog issues.

Comment: I'd consider a digital solution, but I do see a few downsides to that. 1.) Adding an FPGA would complicate the board quite a bit; probably would need to use a BGA package. 2.) Need to develop the FPGA configuration. 3.) Maintaining a clean high quality signal path could get kind of involved once there's AD/DA in the mix. 4.) I'd probably want to use AKM converters and their factory burned down :(.

Answer (score 0):

If you need (up to) the full 24 audio paths through then you need 576 switches (assuming mono), in whatever form.

The AD8113 seems comparably reasonably priced but you'd need 4 to get (up to) 32 x 32 and that's about $120-$150 just for the chips.

Analog **crosspoint switches** don't tend to be cheap. I did an audio/video switcher with similar chips some years ago, controlled by a micro. They did what the datasheet claims, kind of boring in a good way.

Answer (score 0):

> Only one signal at a time per output (no mixing) but any input needs to be routable to any output.

Do you mean only one signal passes through the switch at a time? If so, you only need one 24:1 mux followed by a 1:24 demux.

If you need several signals passing through the switch simultaneously, without interfering with each other, and you can put a firm upper bound N on the number of signals you'll need, and N is less than 24, then you can get a hardware saving by implementing just N of the single channel routers described in the first paragraph.

If you need 24 signals, then you're stuck with a full crosspoint.